# model view controller sample code for yii 2 using active record

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have started reading the yii2 documentation and the Active record query builder now i want to work and practice it but i have trouble in how to make MVC pattern in yii2 which seems a bit hard for me so i wanted to ask you experienced guys to write a sample code for me which in model use a active record to select a thing from a table and pass it to controller and show it in view .i have tried to write that in backend/web/advance/. . . but i had no success in passing data between model and controller and showing it in view .
i do thank You guys in advance .

Comment: Exactly what you need is explained in the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#actions).

Comment: how come i missed that :| that would be a true silly question then . thats for your guilde bizley

Comment: Cheers ;) Have fun with Yii 2.